# how to open new activity through custom dialog button

Tags: android, eclipse

```
public void next(){
    hand.removeCallbacks(run);
    final Dialog d =new Dialog(First.this);
    d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.next_level);              
    d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
    d.setCancelable(false);
    Window window = d.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(300, 300);
    Button next;
    next= (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent(First.this,Second.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
});

    d.show();
}
```

i want to open new activity through custom dialog button when i click on button the app close. anybody help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Added `Second` Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: Could you post log from logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that you need add this:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Else, your app crashed for other reason. Can you put some logCat trace??

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
     d.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout); 
     d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    
   Button next = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id_on_dialog_layout);

     next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

     Intent intent = new Intent(your_class.this,your_destination.class);

     startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```